# Accessing a parent member from the child constructor (templates)

Tags: c++, oop, templates

So i have some simple question/structure:

```
 class Class1 {
   public:
      Class1() {};
      ~Class1() {};
   protected:
      std::string name;
 }

 class Class2 : public Class1
 {
   public:
     Class2() : number(id_generator++) {
       name = "My-name"; // (1) want to access field inherited from Parent
   };

   private:
      const unsigned int number;
      static unsigned int id_generator;
  }
```

a compiler complains for (1): `'name' was not declared in this scope`. What is wrong? It look simple but i don't see it.

EDIT1: just i realized that the error is actually pronounced only here ([here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx%24107) link to the code):

```
#include <string>

template<int dim>
class Class1 {
   public:
      Class1() {};
     ~Class1() {};
   protected:
      std::string name;
 };

template<int dim>
class Class2 : public Class1<dim>
{
   public:
     Class2() : number(id_generator++) {
       name = "My-name"; // (1) want to access field inherited from Parent
     };

   private:
     const unsigned int number;
     static unsigned int id_generator;
};

int main() {}
```

so apparently i mess up something with templates. Sorry, for not writing it first place.

Comment: Missing semicolons aside, the code is fine.

Comment: Compiles fine [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx$91), after adding the semicolons

Comment: @AndyProwl thanks for the link to the code. I actually edited the question so the problem is there now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a template, for unqualified names that refer to members inherited from a base class, you should use the explicit syntax by dereferencing `this`:

```
 Class2() : number(id_generator++) {
     this->name = "My-name"; // (1) want to access field inherited from Parent
 //  ^^^^^^
 };
```

Or, alternatively, you could qualify the name this way:

```
 Class2() : number(id_generator++) {
     Class1<dim>::name = "My-name";
 //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 };
```

Otherwise, the compiler will lookup `name` in the global namespace during the [first phase of name lookup](http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html) and, if not found, will issue an error.

Comment: thanks a lot! I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Missing semicolons aside, the code is fine.

The only possible explanation is that `Class1`, as seen by the compiler, doesn't actually have the `name` member. Do you have multiple classes called `Class1`? Do you have multiple copies of the header file where `Class1` is declared? Is it possible that you've forgotten to save the file before running the compiler?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i actually realized that some crucial parts are missing - templates - and therefore modified the question.